# Ubuntu on late 2008 Macbook pro trackpad presure

Tags: touchpad, macbook-pro

I have Ubuntu installed on my late 2008 Macbook Pro. Everything seems to work great other than the trackpad. When I press on the trackpad lightly I can move the cursor wherever but once I give it a little pressure it stops the cursor in its tracks. How do I fix this?